# A star path finding without grid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Does any one knows any [A*](http://www.heyes-jones.com/astar.html) implementations, where the nodes are not grid? Let say you have a map where only the road is walkable. If I use grid, than the algorithm will search all of the fields of the grid, just to find a path for only 1/3 of them. And if is a big grid ....

So, is there any example on net where A* is implemented without grid? I found this on net, http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=185, which is actually what I'm looking for (scroll down for the A*), but this is incorporated with other stuffs.

I just wanted to know if there is any simpler solution than this? Thanks.